# Implementing map on Option

Tags: scala

Working more on [FP in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) examples, I tried to implement the `Option` trait's `map` function as follows:

```
sealed trait MyOption[+A] {
    def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
        case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

However, compile-time errors show, if I understand correctly, that I'm not pattern-matching correctly for the case of `Some(A)`. Using pattern matching, how can I write the first case to get Some(A) values to match?

```
>scalac MyOption.scala
MyOption.scala:3: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Some[A(in class Some)]
 required: MyOption[A(in trait MyOption)]
                case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                     ^
MyOption.scala:3: error: not found: value a
                case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
                                       ^
two errors found
```

Comment: you are mixing up Option and MyOption, the return type of MyOption#map should be MyOption, not Option.  are you sure the Some you are using is a MyOption and not an Option?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to define map in terms of Some and None which are subclasses of the Scala-provided Option trait, rather than in terms of subclasses of your own trait. Try something like:

```
sealed trait MyOption[+A] {
    import MyOption._
    def map[B](f: A => B): MyOption[B] = this match {
        case MySome(a) => MySome(f(a))
        case _ => MyNone
    }
}

object MyOption {
  case class MySome[+A](a: A) extends MyOption[A]
  case object MyNone extends MyOption[Nothing]
}
```